# Customize vimeo RSS output to get / extract the url

Tags: video, rss, extract, feed, vimeo

I have an rss feed from **vimeo**, but the item.url is something like this:
https://vimeo.com/channels/wineaftercoffee/126060304

instead of something like this (which i what I need):
https://vimeo.com/126060304

I'm trying to get a feed that I can send to twitter that would have the video in it (via IFTTT or something similar)

I started playing with yahoo pipes but didn't get too far:
[image: Yahoo pipe work in progress]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Used a simple [Yahoo pipe][1] to make the item.url remove "channels/wineaftercoffee/"

here it is:

https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=7403f934382f71eb42c8f3462b690c5a

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuS5m.png